# Laravel Undefined Property Error with Google Pagespeed API

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5, pagespeed

I'm a beginner in using laravel. For my webapp I want to use the Google API PageSpeed. When visiting /pagespeed, it gives me this error: ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Undefined property: stdClass::$ruleScore

Also I'm not sure if i made a correct return. I just want to show the meassured data on the /pagespeed page.

Couldn't really find an answer for my problem, I hope you can help.

I used the pagespeed.php code from https://gist.github.com/typhonius/6259822/revisions and put this in my PagespeedController:

```
public function pageSpeed(){
$url = 'https://www.facebook.com';
$key = 'my API key';
// View https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v1/getting_started#before_starting to get a key
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?url=$url&key=$key"));
$dat = $data->formattedResults->ruleResults;
foreach($dat as $d) {
  $name = $d->localizedRuleName;
  $score = $d->ruleScore;
  print "\nTest: " . $name . "\n";
  print "Score: " . $score . "\n";
  if ($score != 100) {
    if (isset($d->urlBlocks[0]->header->args)) {
      $advice_header = replace_placeholders($d->urlBlocks[0]->header->format, $d->urlBlocks[0]->header->args);
    }
    else {
      $advice_header = $d->urlBlocks[0]->header->format;
    }
    print "Advice: " . $advice_header . "\n";
    foreach ($d->urlBlocks[0]->urls as $url) {
      $advice = replace_placeholders($url->result->format, $url->result->args);
      print $advice . "\n";
    }
  }
};
function replace_placeholders($format, $args) {
  $i = 1;
  foreach ($args as $arg) {
    $format = str_replace("\$" . $i, "$arg->value", $format);
    $i++;
  }
  return view('pagespeed')->with('format');
}
```

This is in my views folder: pagespeed.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<h1>Page Speed</h1>
@endsection
```

This is my Route in web.php:

```
Route::get('/pagespeed', 'PagespeedController@pageSpeed');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$score = $d->ruleScore;
```

to

```
$score = $d->score;
```

Comment: Hi, this didn't change it: Undefined property: stdClass::$score

Comment: where do i set this?

Comment: `foreach($dat as $d) {` before this line

Comment: Welcome, post ur answer so it will be useful to others